# PHP Excel records display into web page

Tags: php

I have Excel Cell value and Cell position in the database table. Now I want to render these information from database table to web page.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

example:
database table fields are FieldValue FieldPosition

```
FieldValues | FieldPosition

100                 A1
200                 B1
username            C1
testing             A2
```

This is my table details.

Note:cell position is alpha numeric, so sorting will now works.

Comment: So have you looked at any of the libraries for working with Excel files in PHP such as PHPExcel (http://phpexcel.codeplex.com)? Or are you just hoping that somebody will write the code for you?

Comment: Do you have Excel style information to work with? Or is it simply a set of references and values in a database table?

Comment: Select the data from your database ordered by row than by column from `cellpostion`, then loop through that data echoing it into an HTML table, setting a new row every time the row reference changes

Comment: I've used PHPExcel in an assignment.... that should work....it's quite a big library

Comment: @MarkBaker:I dont want, some one get pain for me, i dont like as well. if you saying like these, then forums are not needed, forums is nothing but sharing thoughts/ideas. if some one know very much on that logic, then they dont come and ask. any way thanks for your nice suggestion, which you provided below.

Comment: @MarkBaker: i dont think order by will work, because order by will order the records like a1,2,a3,b1,b2,b3, if i am wrong please guide me.

Comment: @pinkpanther thanks for suggestion. PHPExcel will help us to dislay records from Excel into WEB only know. but my request is little different. i am have these cell values and cell position in the table. now i want display records from DB Table into web.

Comment: @Bharanikumar your question is not clear. Update your question describing your problem clearly.

Comment: @pinkpanther  as per request i have updated my question in short

Comment: @Bharanikumar Your question makes no sense. Why do you need that 2nd step with "DB Table"? Is there a need to change some data in DB or there is a need to display some data from DB in your web page? I see no difference between your Excel table and expected result.

Comment: @Deele he said excel file only lasts for few seconds in his server and cannot do that...

Comment: A straight ORDER BY won't work, you need to split the cellpostion into row and column in your SQL query to use that method... alternatively, a library like PHPExcel will allow you to set each cell individually by its cellpostion, and then render to HTML

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using PHPExcel:

```
// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Read data from the database and populate the PHPExcel object
$query = "SELECT cellposition, cellvalue FROM datatable";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->setCellValue(
                $row->cellposition,
                $row->cellvalue
            );
    }
    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

// Write the PHPExcel object to browser as HTML
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are existing libraries for your needs:

- [php-excel-reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/)
- [phpexcelreader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/)
- [PHPExcel](http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel)

PS: You know, this question has been answered previously, you should use search, before asking.

Comment: I have suggested this to him..it seems it's not what he wants see his comment to me under the question

Comment: @Deele; @pinkpanther  yes, correct, these suggested plugins are used to read the excel files, but my functionality is little different, i have these excel values, excel position in the database table, i want to render and display into web page. this output lookup and excel lookup shoule be same.

Comment: @Bharanikumar posting some screen shot might help in this case

Comment: @pinkpanther plz chk updated one. thanks

Comment: Well PHPExcel can `write` Excel data as HTML, so that is an option

Comment: @MarkBaker you got his question wrongly....he has a database table describing cellvalue and its positions from a excel sheet. Now using that information he has to display the data in webpage

Comment: @pinkpanther - I haven't got his question wrong.... look at my answer

Comment: @MarkBaker sorry :) now you got what he exactly wants....